# Django: Booleanfield with default value triggers NotNullViolation on 'get_or_create'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on a Django web application (with a Postgres database) that contains a model with the following field:

```
Loan(models.Model):
    (...)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    print_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        unique=True,
    )
    (...)
```

However, our application is currently triggering Sentry errors on the following piece of code:

```
loan, created = Loan.objects.get_or_create(
   print_code=data['print_code']
)
```

Its raising the following error:

```
null value in column "active" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, print1722, f, null)
```

The traceback also contains the `Loan.DoesNotExist` error, so I know Django is trying to create a new `Loan` instance - without providing a value for the `active` field, but as can be seen in the code above it has a default value.

The problem is that so far I've been unable to replicate the problem locally and we don't have shell access to the code that is running live. All unittests also pass without problems, even when I explicitly created some tests to create `Loan` objects without the `active` field being set.

```
# Does not fail.
def test_null_value_on_active_field(self):
    test_object, created = Loan.objects.get_or_create(print_code='test')
    self.assertEqual(True, test_object.active)
    self.assertEqual(True, created)
```

In all my attempts the code behaved as expected and filled the field with the default `True` value. Yet the error keeps occurring, so I must be missing something.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a unit test that creates a `Loan` object in exactly this way -- using `get_or_create()` and providing no value for `active`?

Comment: I must confess I initially did not (it used a 'create' instead of a 'get_or_create') I've since updated the tests (and included in the question above) - the test passes without problems and assigns the correct value.

Comment: In that unit test, are you checking that `created` is true?

Comment: I wasnt explicitly, but I've changed the test do so and it still passes.

Comment: Is it possible that the live database _actually does_ contain a row where `active` is null (maybe it was created before the database constraint was added), and thus `get_or_create()` correctly finds that row?